# Should I use fontspec with XeLaTeX + xeCJK?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, xecjk

Everything is in the title.

I am currently typesetting a bilingual (French/Japanese) document using XeLatex.
`xeCJK` takes care of the Japanese part and `polyglossia` takes care of the French part.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho ProN}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
```

It works great.

Now, I'm reading here and there that a lot of people make use of the `fontspec` package.
Should I use it too? What would be the benefit?

Comment: done. I'm using the `memoir` class

Comment: I should add that the document is my doctoral thesis (200+ pages).

Comment: You *are* using fontspec. xeCJK loads it: It contains the line `\RequirePackage{fontspec}[2012/05/01]`. And yes you should use it.